# How to create a graph database in TinkerPop/Rextser using the Rexster Docker image and Bulbs?

Tags: docker, tinkerpop, bulbs, rexster

How do I create a new database?
I am using the Rexster Docker image from "https://github.com/konrade/docker-rexster" to get a functional Rexster server up and running. 
It is run using the following command:

```
sudo docker.io run -i -t -P 6cced29c46a3 /bin/bash
```

And verify which port is assigned to Rexster's necessary 8182 like so:

```
sudo docker.io port <container id> 8182
```

I am confident the server is running as I get webpage with the TinkerPop characters when I go to url

```
'http://localhost:49153'.
```

But I cannot get the simple example on the bulbs Quickstart section to execute succesfully.
Here is the simple code I am trying to execute:

```
from bulbs.rexster import Graph, Config
config = Config('http://localhost:49153/graphs/dantest')
g = Graph(config)
```

Would creating a neo4j database solve my problems?
if so, what would be the code used to create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bulbs doesn't create the graph for you -- to do that, you must configure your rexster.xml to create a specific graph.

The default graph name is `emptygraph` so this should work out of the box...

```
>>> from bulbs.rexster import Graph, Config
>>> config = Config('http://localhost:49153/graphs/emptygraph')
>>> g = Graph(config)
```